# Can't verify my new Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I got this email from Google after setting up my new account:

> Congratulations on creating your brand new Gmail address, ************@gmail.com. Please keep this email for your records, as it contains an important verification code that you may need should you ever encounter problems or forget your password.
>
> You can login to your account at http://mail.google.com/
>
> Enjoy!
>
> The Gmail Team

There is a verification code at the bottom, but when I use the login, it asks me to create a new account and there is no place to put in the verification code. Help!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a delay between receiving your verification code and your account being available for use. Note the verification code is not required for logging in - it is in case of problems later. So use the sign in details you chose when setting up the account.